# Is there a loop "start-over"?

Tags: javascript, loops

- There is `continue;` to stop the loop and move to the *next* loop
- There is `break;` to stop the loop and move to the *end* of the loop

Isn't there some kind of `start;` that stop the loop and move to the *beginning* of the loop?

I know it is easy to achieve all of these three actions by just modifying the value of `i`, but I always try to look for already built-it functions.

Comment: you can restart loop by just resting counter like in for loop you can reset index to 0  , it will restart

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No - there is no keyword or other way to do it automatically.

As you already mentioned you can just modify the loop condition variable(s) within your loop. Easy if it's a simple `i` counter, but of course you may have more initialisation to do than just a simple counter.

Or you can do something like the following:

```
restartLoop:
while (true) {
   for (var i=0, j=100000, x="test"; i < 1000; i++, j--, x+= ".") {
      if (/*some condition, want to restart the loop*/)
          continue restartLoop;
   }
   break;
}
```

The `continue restartLoop` will jump back out to continue with the next iteration of the `while` loop, which then immediately starts the `for` loop from the beginning including all of the initialisation code. If the `for` exits normally the `break` statement after it will break out of the containing while loop.

I don't really recommend doing this in a general sense, but if your loop initialisation process was *really* complicated it could be worth it because then you wouldn't need to repeat it all inside the loop. If you needed to do even more initialisation than fits nicely in the `for` statement's initialisation expression you can easily put it just before the `for` loop inside the `while` and it will all be re-run...

Comment: Yes, `continue` and `break` can both be used with a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) so that you can `continue` or `break` an outer loop from inside an inner loop (through as many levels of nesting as desired). Of course in my answer I've abused this a little bit since my outer loop has no purpose at all other than to allow restarting of the inner loop, but anyway there are more serious applications as I'm sure you can imagine.

Comment: is it possible to label the beginning of a loop, and use break to jump to it? (is that the case, I think I found an interesting way to achieve what I want)

Comment: No, `break somelabel` will exit the loop that `somelabel` applies to and continue with the statement after the loop. That's why I used `continue` with a containing loop in my answer. What you are looking for is [`goto`](http://www.xkcd.com/292/), which JavaScript doesn't have - thank goodness. ([Unless you use this add-on.](http://summerofgoto.com/))

Comment: +1 for bringing to our knowledge this esoteric JS feature. ([Use with caution](http://xkcd.com/292/))

Comment: I worked with spaghetti-code before. I avoid it in modern languages as much as possible. I actually think the return trick is the best solution for this. Resetting `i` isn't pretty either.

Answer (score 32):

Resetting the value of your loop variable to the initial value then calling `continue` is as close as you'll get.

For example:

```
for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
  if(somecondition) {
    i=-1; continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: I belive `i=-1` is more appropriated (I could be wrong), it depends on if the `continue` prevents the `i++` (which I don't know)

Comment: @ajax333221 is correct. `continue` definitely jumps to the update expression before re-evaluating the condition.

Comment: No need to test, [the doco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue#Description) says so explicitly...

Comment: Can I ask why don't we make `i = 0` ?

Comment: @jason Because the `i++` will bring it back up one more. `-1` means the `i++` will reset you to `0` as intended.

Comment: I guess this block could be easily be changed into a `while`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid jumps or the equivalent of goto statements that many of us have been trained to avoid, you could use a local function for the loop and a test on the return value to see if you should just call it again:

```
function doItAll() {
    // put state variables other than the actual loop control here

    function doTheLoop() {
        for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
            if (somecondition) {
                return(true);    // run the loop again
            }
        }
        return(false);   // done running the loop
    }
    while (doTheLoop()) {}
    // do some things after the loop
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Yet you can beautify and enhance it by putting while and for into the same function.

Answer (score 3):

No.  (Just to rule out a "I just haven't heard of it, either" - it isn't mentioned at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements.)

Answer (score 3):

`continue` works by simply skipping the rest of the loop body. `break` works by skipping the rest of the loop body and then ending the loop. A `start` function would have to somehow "rewind" the state of the program - but not all of the state of the program, since presumably you don't want to lose what you did, either - to where it was when the loop began, which is not something that any programming language that I have seen provides.

Comment: I doubt the data will be lost, if you loop starting at 0 and you after some loops assign the value of -1 it will start looping again. I have used this very often.

Comment: Yes - but to do this automatically the language needs to know which one the loop variable is.

Answer (score 2):

You could have the loop in a function that calls itself recursively:

```
function loopIt(numTimes) {
            if (numTimes < 3) {
                for (x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
                    if (x == 5) {
                        loopIt(numTimes+1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }     
        }
```

You can obviously change the conditions to fit you logic as the above is a simple example.