# Is there a redo statement in JS for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a scenario where a check inside a for loop is executed and if it is `true`, I want that the code for this iteration runs again, so instead of a `continue` statement, I would like to have a `redo` statement <s>just like in Python</s>:

```
for (v of myList) {
    if (myCheck) {
        v.attr = someValue;
        redo;
    }
    ...
}
```

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766910/is-there-a-loop-start-over), from which I would do the following:

```
for ([i,v] of myList) {
    if (myCheck) {
        v.attr = someValue;
        i-=1; continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

I am just wondering if there is another way to do this.

Comment: If `myList` is an array, you can use `for (let i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) { ... myList[i]... i--; }`

Comment: Python has a redo statement?

Comment: @AndyRay: You were right. I have confused it with something else. Edited in the question

Comment: `while loop` is the better candidate for this use case. beware of creating an infinite loop though., also what will make it `true` in next iteration?

Comment: @AZ_ : Basically the setting of `v.attr = someValue;` makes `myCheck = false`, so when the current step in the loop is redone, it will pass the if statement

Answer (score 1):

You could use a basic `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    if (myCheck) {
        v.attr = someValue;
        i--; 
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps,